# How can I dispatch Firefox or Google Chrome with Python?

Tags: python, windows, firefox

How can I do this with Firefox or Google Chrome?

```
ie = win32com.client.Dispatch('InternetExplorer.Application')
ie.visible = 1
ie.navigate('http://google.com')
```

Is there a way to do it?

ps: I need to use the ReadyState with it... for example `while (ie.ReadyState != 4):`, or in other words, I need some command that wait until the page loads completely until do the next command, that's why I need the dispatch, that currently work very good with IE

Comment: Why? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Selenium doesnt work at I expected to the job =/

Comment: Have you tried http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PythonBindings What doesn't work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox does not expose a COM object; this is not possible.  (AFAIK)

You can use the [`webbrowser` module](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/module-webbrowser.html) to open a URL in the user's default browser.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [`webbrowser`](http://docs.python.org/library/webbrowser.html) module in the Python standard library.

Comment: webbrowser module can't give me the status ready of the dispatch... so I can use some ifs with it.... for example: while (ie.ReadyState != 4):

Comment: Do you really need that?  If so, I guess you could try something with the `subprocess` module instead of `webbrowser`... but in that case, update your question to better specify your requirements.

Comment: subprocess can give me something like the ReadyState? For example, can it wait until the page load completely to run the next command? That's what I want actually

Comment: `subprocess` would at least tell you whether the process launched properly, and would give you access to its standard output and error streams. It's possible that if Firefox produces output to indicate when it loads a page, you could parse the text on those streams to tell when the page is loaded. Otherwise, you'd have to write some sort of interface between Python and the native code in Firefox.